# @Inject a Morphia DAO with CDI?

Tags: mongodb, jakarta-ee, cdi, morphia, inject

I'm writing a Java EE 6 application that makes use of Morphia to persist objects to MongoDB.  I'd like to be able to `@Inject` my DAO classes where necessary, so I created a Factory class that instantiates the DAO appropriately.  It looks something like this:

```
public class MyDAOFactory {

    @Inject
    private Datastore mongoDatastore = null;

    /**
     * Creates the DAO
     */
    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    public MyDAO createDAO() {
        MyDAO dao = new MyDAO(
                this.mongoDatastore);
        return dao;
    }
}
```

The code compiles fine, but when I run my application on JBoss EAP 6.1 it complains because `MyDAO` does not have a no-arg constructor.  I would add one, but the Morphia BasicDAO class does not have one either, so I don't know that it would work that way.

Is there a way to `@Inject` a DAO instance into my EJB, Servlet, etc.?  Or do I need to manually instantiate it every time?

Comment: I don't know Morphia, but I *guess* the no-args constructor is needed for CDI to be able to proxy the MyDAO component. I think it could also be a protected (or even private?) constructor, so it will no mess with your public interface. If however such a constructor cannot be written (e.g. because you cannot provide appropriate arguments to a parent class [`BasicDAO`] constructor), then the factory is your only chance I can think of.

Comment: Yes, the proxy issue is why CDI is complaining about the lack of a no-arg constructor.  However, I would think that implementing a Factory class like this would get around it.  Is that not the case?  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that CDI needs the no-arg constructor for `MyDAO` for some reason. Maybe because of how you use this bean (see specs ch.5.4 "Client Proxies" for possible reasons).

You *cannot* create a default constructor, because the base class does not have one and, from what I see from the [code](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/blob/master/morphia/src/main/java/org/mongodb/morphia/dao/BasicDAO.java) the `super` constructors make immediate use of their args. Therefore passing null to `super()` from a no-arg constructor will throw errors.

My suggestion is to create an interface (optionally extending `org.mongodb.morphia.dao.DAO`), e.g. `MyDAOInterface` that has all public business methods of `MyDAO`. Then modify `MyDAO` to implement this interface and change your producer to return `MyDAOInterface`:

```
public interface MyDAOInterface extends DAO {...}

public class MyDAO implements MyDAOInterface {
    // same implementation
}

public class MyDAOFactory {
    @Inject
    private Datastore mongoDatastore = null;

    /**
     * Creates the DAO
     */
    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    public MyDAOInterface createDAO() {
        MyDAO dao = new MyDAO(this.mongoDatastore);
        return dao;
    }
}
```

---

By the way, programming to interfaces has the extra benefit of making your code more testable, so it is worth the minor hassle.